# Real address giving PO BOX error because of having the phrase "box" in it

Tags: c#, regex

I'm working with a validation method that is intended to block PO boxes. As written, it currently blocks real addresses like "42 Boxwood Ln" because of the phrase "Box". How can I fix this - perhaps only blocking shorter strings that appear to be PO boxes? For example, making sure the string "Box" must be followed by a number?

Here's the current code:

```
private static bool IsPostOfficeBox(string add1, string add2)
{
    if (add1 == null) return false;
        
    var poBoxReg = new Regex(@"(?i)\b(?:p(?:ost)?\.?\s*[o0](?:ffice)?\.?\s*b(?:[o0]x)?|b[o0]x)");

    var isPOBox = poBoxReg.IsMatch(add1);
    if (add2 == null || isPOBox) return isPOBox;

    return poBoxReg.IsMatch(add2);
}
```

Comment: What are you asking us to do?

Comment: This regex fails any address that is passed by the user and has the word "box" in it. It considers it as a PO Box Number and not as an address and gives an error.

Comment: So you want a Regex that looks for "box followed by at least one number"?

Comment: yes that is what i am looking for

Comment: When add1 is passed in as "42 Boxwood Ln" and add2 is passed in as "Apt 111". What I'm looking for is that to "isPOBox" to come as "false" where as now it is coming as "true".

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

- match *box* followed by digits - `box\s\d`
- match with word boundaries, i.e. *box* but not *boxwood* - `\bbox\b`

Use both of these to match "PO Box 1242" but not "42 Boxwood Ln". [See example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0PgOhx) (notice RegexOptions.IgnoreCase to match case-insensitive).

Comment: A quick search on Google Maps confirmed to me that there are many Box Lane's, for example, in the UK. Mainly because it can also be the name of a bush shrub. So you cannot assume that word boundaries are a solid way of flagging a PO Box.

Comment: The fiddle shows both rules together i.e. `\bbox\b\s\d` which should not match "Box Lane" as no digits after "Box"

Comment: Ah, your answer reads more like "either of these would work", not "use both of these"